# Adding 0 to months in jQuery date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery script which returns the current date into a text box. However, when a month with only one digit is displayed (e.g. 8) I want it to place a 0 before it (e.g. 08) and not place a 0 before it if it has 2 digits (e.g. 11).

How can I do this? I hope you can understand my question. Here is my jQuery code:

```
var myDate = new Date();
var prettyDate =myDate.getDate() + '' + (myDate.getMonth()+1) + '' + myDate.getFullYear();
$("#date").val(prettyDate);
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
( '0' + (myDate.getMonth()+1) ).slice( -2 );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qaF2r/1/

Comment: This is beautiful, I deleted my answer in shame :-P +1

Comment: It is beutiful... but I like mine more ;) (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I don't like so much string concatenation:

```
var month = myDate.getMonth()+1,
    prettyData = [
        myDate.getDate(), 
        (month < 10 ? '0' +  month : month), 
        myDate.getFullYear()
    ].join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myDate = new Date();
var newMonth = myDate.getMonth()+1;
var prettyDate =myDate.getDate() + '' + (newMonth < 9 ? "0"+newMonth:newMonth) + '' +         myDate.getFullYear();
$("#date").val(prettyDate);
```

Comment: You got the values in the ternary operator the other way round ;)

Comment: Oops, pressed the wrong symbol key, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
function addZ(n) {
  return (n < 10? '0' : '') + n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of JS libraries that provide good string formatting. This one does it c# style. http://www.masterdata.dyndns.org/r/string_format_for_javascript/

Answer (score 0):

```
(myDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().replace(/(^.$)/,"0$1")
```

I love regex :)