# Time Doesnt Populate in the Dropdown - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, which works well but the problem is when I select the date it doesn't populate the `selected-time` dropdown, its blank. It should populate the correct available hours for the selected date in that dropdown

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #booking-form {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="calendar"></div>
  <div id="booking-form">
    <h2>Book an appointment</h2>
    <p>Please select a date and time:</p>
    <form action="book-appointment.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" id="selected-date" name="selected-date" value="">
      <select id="selected-time" name="selected-time"></select>
      <br><br>
      <button type="submit">Book Appointment</button>
    </form>
  </div>
 <script>
  // Use available dates and hours from PHP
  var availableDates = ["2023-02-17","2023-02-19","2023-02-20","2023-02-25","2023-02-27"];
  var availableDateTime = {"2023-02-17":["09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00"],"2023-02-19":["09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00"],"2023-02-20":["09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00"],"2023-02-25":["09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00"],"2023-02-27":["09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00"]};

  // Initialize calendar
  $('#calendar').datepicker({
    minDate: 0, // Set minDate to 0 to disable past dates
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var dateString = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      return [$.inArray(dateString, availableDates) != -1];
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      // Show booking form on date selection
      $('#booking-form').show();

      // Store selected date
      $('#selected-date').val(dateText);

      // Clear previous options from time select
      $('#selected-time').empty();

      // Get selected date
      var selectedDate = new Date(dateText);

      // Add available hours for the selected date to time select
      var availableHoursForSelectedDate = availableDateTime[selectedDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (selectedDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + selectedDate.getDate()];

      $.each(availableHoursForSelectedDate, function(i, time) {
        var optionText = time;
        var optionValue = time;
        $('#selected-time').append($('<option>').text(optionText).val(optionValue));
      });

      // Disable unavailable hours in time select
      var currentDate = new Date();
      if (selectedDate.getDate() === currentDate.getDate()) {
        // Disable hours before current hour
        var currentHour = currentDate.getHours();
        $('#selected-time option').each(function() {
          var optionText = $(this).text();
          var hour = parseInt(optionText.substr(0, 2));
          if (hour < currentHour) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
          }
        });
      }
      else {
        // Disable all hours before 9am and after 5pm
        $('#selected-time option').each(function() {
          var optionText = $(this).text();
          var startHour = parseInt(optionText.substr(0, 2));
          var endHour = parseInt(optionText.substr(8, 2));
          if (startHour < 9 || endHour > 16) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, your issue is with month value . i.e : `(selectedDate.getMonth() + 1)` this returns 2,3..etc .But , in your array you need `02` . You can solve that by adding `0` to your month if the month < 9 . Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019578/adding-0-to-months-in-jquery-date) for solving it.

Comment: @Swati thanks for the answer I trued but it didn't worked, can you share fiddle (code) for my reference?

Comment: Here is an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/pe1245ch/

Comment: @76484 works great, thank you, please post the answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the key you construct for your lookup on the `availableDateTime` object. Specifically, it doesn't include the `0` padding for the month and day values. For example, today is February 18, 2023; but `selectedDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (selectedDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + selectedDate.getDate()` will evaluate to `2023-2-18`, not `2023-02-18`.

Following the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7019596/3397771) that @Swati shared, we learn how to left pad our formatted digits with a `'0'`, which we would need to do for both the month and day values of our formatted date.

The code becomes:

```
var dateKey = `${selectedDate.getFullYear()}-${('0' + (selectedDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}-${('0' + selectedDate.getDate()).slice(-2)}`;
    
var availableHoursForSelectedDate = availableDateTime[dateKey];
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/pe1245ch/) is an example fiddle.